# Differentiating-아/어서

Tags: grammar

This can be used as a temporal particle for related events—e.g. I cut the apples and then ate them—or as a particle to express cause—e.g. I am hungry so I want to eat. Thus, is there a reliable way to tell them apart? Or is it left solely to the context of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it solely depends on the context. Note that the suffixes can also mean manner, and I think the OP's first example (temporal ordering) is more natural to interpret as manner. Examples of `-어/-아`, `-어서` as manner suffix

> - 걸어서 가다 
>    to go by walking
> - 달려 가다 
>    to go by running
> - 잘라 먹다 vs 통으로 먹다
> - 깍아서 먹다 vs 껍질째 먹다

And finally, `-어/-아` also can be a connection suffix for some light verbs. For example,

> - 다 써 *버렸다* 
>    used all *up*
> - 한 번 써 *보았다* 
>    *tried* to use it once
> - 끝없이 졸라 *대다* 
>     *keep* nagging endlessly

and more.

On a side note: Generally, philosophically, and epistemically, beyond the suffixes in question, it's really hard to differentiate temporal orders from causal orders in many cases. The confusion, I think, has been the origin of many conspiracy theories, for example.

#까마귀_날자_배_떨어졌다